# Skeet-Lighter - Highlight all Questions/Comments/Answers by Jon Skeet

Tags: script, google-chrome

[image: Highlighted Skeet Comment]

**About**

This extension will highlight all Questions/Posts/Comments made by Jon Skeet on the StackExchange websites.

For those who wish to be notified when Jon has weighed in on a question, Skeet-Lighter is for you. All questions, answers and comments made by Jon Skeet will be highlighted in blue.

Additionally, tell at a glance if Jon Skeets presence can be felt in the question. When present, Jons icon will appear next to the question title. No longer will you need to scroll down, wondering if the legend himself has bestowed his heavenly wisdom upon the question at hand!

[image: Title Bar Skeet Indicator]

**Version:** 1.0

**Platform:** Google Chrome

**Download:** [Skeet-Lighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skeet-lighter/eojpaklfgiiedojmohpdeadpajodcbnj)

**Contact:** Twitter: [@ObsidianDev](https://twitter.com/ObsidianDev)

**Code:** Written using jQuery, with Mutation-Summary

Comment: Hahaha, amazing app! It's only for Chrome?

Comment: Thanks. At the moment it's purely chrome, yeah. Although it's only jquery, so I could investigate other browsers if people wanted it.